# Angular 8: How to create enum from json REST API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, enums

How to create enum from a json rest api?

I have this service.ts

```
getDataFromJson(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`../../../assets/gender.json`)
      .pipe(map(data => {
        return data;
    }));
  }
```

but it returns as

```
[
  {
    "name": "Female",
  },
  {
    "name": "Male",
  }
]
```

using this code

```
getGenders: any = {}

getGender() {
    this.options.getDataFromJson().subscribe(data => {
      this.getGenders = data;
    })
  }
```

instead of this format

```
{
    Male = 'Male',
    Female = 'Female',
}
```

I want it to return is as type enum and place it in my gender.ts just like this.

```
export enum Gender {
    Male = 'Male',
    Female = 'Female',
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467271/4300608) answer.

Comment: this should be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058699/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-generate-enums-on-typescript-based-on-object-keys

Answer (score 1):

I don't think enum is the correct word here. Please consider a constant.

Imagine you have a gender.json file, which includes the following in your project.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Female"
  },
  {
    "name": "Male"
  }
]
```

Now you want to create another variable in gender.ts which holds the expected format.

```
export const genders = {
    Male: 'Male',
    Female: 'Female',
};
```

To build this genders constant dynamically you need to do 2 things.

1st: Go to your compilerOptions and include those 2 lines:

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"allowSyntheticImports": true
```

2nd:
Go back to gender.ts and import the json file. Then transform the json's content to the expected format.

```
import genderJson from './gender.json';

export const genders = genderJson
  .map(gender => gender.name).reduce((acc, gender) => {
    acc[gender] = gender;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

See working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uocg2j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgender.ts